# PHPStorm - перевод строки не работает

Tags: строки, phpstorm, перевод

```
// Нужно чтобы строки были с новой строки:
print_r("aaa");
print_r("\n");
print_r("bbb");
// результат: aaa bbb

// и этот вариант дает тот же результат
print_r("aaa\nbbb");
// результат: aaa bbb
```

Comment: именно print_r нужно? он же не для того

Comment: Нет, print_r не принципиально. Можно echo, print или что-то другое. У меня не получается (в phpStorm) при помощи \n сделать переход на новую строку, никакими вариантами. Может какие-то настройки нужно сделтаь в phpStorm. Я вообще ничего не нашел по этому вопросу.

Comment: где вы смотрите результат выполнения?

Comment: в phpStorm есть кнопка с браузером, я ее тыкаю и запускается результат. Кактотак

Comment: В браузере нужно `<br>`, т.к. там HTML, а  вот в консоли `\n`

Comment: https://ru.code-basics.com/languages/php/lessons/escape-characters#editor - здеь урок, в котором я задание выполнил правильно, а когда попробовал этот же код напасть в PS, то результата не увидел

Comment: см комментарий выше

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html

Comment: Да, <br> сработал так как вы говорите, и результат нужный достигнут ))) Спасибо!

Comment: midnightelf18 - спасибо большое за ссылку, это то что нужно!